# K-means Clustering algorithm problems

Tags: machine-learning, python, k-means

I am trying to implement k-means clustering algorithm, but I am confused about calculating the distance and update(move) cluster centroids. For example, let's say that I have 2 features. One of them is `weight={2,4,6,8,11,14,21}` and the other one is `height={4,6,7,8,9,12,14}`. So, in the coordinate system my points are `x1={2,4},x2={4,6},x3={6,7}` and so on. Then, I initialize the cluster centroids randomly, doesn't matter how many there are for now, but they have coordinates too. Let's say `μ1={4,2}`. At this point, I understand how do I calculate distance with Euclidean distance.

[image]

My code for calculating distance:

```
def get_distance(x1,x2,s1,s2):
      return np.sqrt(np.power(s1-x1,2)+np.power(s2-x2,2))
```

Now I get a distance.

My first question is how cluster assignment step(first step in loop) will know which centroid assign to c(i).I mean,am I supposed to look at each centroid for understand which sample(x(i)) is close to it and then I should assign centroid to c(i), right?

My second question, let's say I got distances and I have c(1,2..,n) array now. Second step in algorithm which is called move(update) centroid step, we are calculate μ. According to formula, this μ is the average of points assigned to clusters so for example μ1=[x(3) + x(4) + x(6)] / 3. However, here our μ was a point in coordinate system, right? I mean, μ1 was {4,2}. How can this be possible? It's a point not a variable. It has coordinates. Well, if it will become a variable let's say μ1=5, how can I subtract ||x(i)-μ|| then? x is a coordinate.

My last question is very simple. For this example, I have two features weight and height. What is the maximum number of features that we can use in k-mean? Is it possible to use k-mean algorithms for many many features? For instance, my first feature is height and the second is weight and the third is width fourth and so on.

I hope, I explained my problem clearly. If not, sorry for the bad English. I think these three questions are independent questions, so you can answer one of them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia says: "Assign each observation to the cluster whose mean yields the least within-cluster sum of squares (WCSS)"

I think in your case, this is translatable to: $c_i$ is assigned to the closest centroid by euclidean distance.

For your second question, the centroid should $\mu$ should have the same number of dimensions as each training point $x_i$. They are both points in the co-ordinate system.

You can use a high number of features with K-means, for example, text analytics might reduce a corpora of news articles to 10,000+ dimensions. Depending on the package you use these might be represented as a sparse matrix.

Comment: for my second question,you said μ and x(i) must be same dimension,but when you are calculating μ , you are using a formula which is find an average of samples and it's giving to you an average ,you know.How do I subtract x-μ then?

Comment: @Mus, The centroid should also be a co-ordinates in a space that is the same dimension as each example